# How to publish WebApp as Azure Virtual Application from TFS Release (vNext)

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-web-app-service, tfsbuild, azure-active-directory

I need to publish 3 webapp to azure using release manager from TFS, and I need all of these 3 apps inside wwwroot subfolder:
wwwroot\app1
wwwroot\app2
wwwroot\app3
This is because I have a azure virtual application pointing to each of this folders.

I have a release for each app. Each app should deploy not to wwwroot, but to a folder inside wwwroot (app1, app2 or app3).

At this moment what I'm doing as a workaround is deploying a package (zip) with the name of the folder that I need (app1, app2 or app3), however, this is just a workaround, because if I activate "clean" in the release task, this clean all wwwroot folders and clean the other apps.

Is there anyway to deploy using some Task to a specific folder instead root folder (wwwroot)? Or, is there a way to deploy to azure virtual application?

If not, is it possible to send me a powershell command to delete a specific folder in the wwwroot?

I'm using "Azure Web App Deployment" task that uses Publish-AzureWebsiteProject PS command, but I don't know if it's possible to send some argument to send this to a specific folder inside wwwroot? Is there some argument to do that?

Thank you all for the availability

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use the [AzureRM Web App Deployment task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) released by Microsoft which allows for **virtual directories**.

[image]

---

***Update***

It's a build-in task called Azure APP Service Deploy
[image]

The task you are using-- **[Azure Web App Deployment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/azure-web-app-deployment)**  is **deprecated**.

> ***NOTE:*** This task has been deprecated. To update Azure App Services using Web Deploy or Kudu REST APIs, use the Azure App Service
>   Deploy task.
>
> We recommend you replace the Azure Web App Deployment task with the
>   Azure App Service Deploy task in all your build or release
>   definitions.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I install this task. This task does not appear in Extensions. What is the steps to do that installation?

Comment: @HLourenco  ...Sorry, forgot have I installed this or not. It's just list in my vsts. You may try to download the source code , package the extension and then publish/install it. Detail ways please refer : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/publish/overview

Comment: @HLourenco It's a built-in task for TFS2017update1 and above. The task you are using-- [Azure Web App Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment)  is **deprecated**. If you are stilling using TFS2015, suggest you upgrade you TFS to latest version. More details please see my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. Using cURL to upload by FTP and I can control each individual folder.

Anyway, if someone knows how to deploy directly to a virtual app directory, please provide answer :)

Thank you